# Simple PHP web crawler to submit form and store the returned results

Tags: php, web-crawler

For a system I am developing I need to programmatically go to a specific page. Fill out one field in the form (I know the id and name of the input element), submit it and store the results.

I have seen a few different Perl, python and java classes that do this. However I would like to do this using PHP and havent found anything as of yet.

I do have the permission to do this from the site i am getting the information from as well.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can submit POST to the 'src' of this form, and parse result after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at David Walsh's simple explanation.

http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

You can easily store the response (in this example, $result) in your database or logfile.

Answer (score 1):

Usually PHP crawlers/scrapers use CURL - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.
It allows you to make a query from the server where PHP runs and get response from the website that you need to crawl. It returns response data in plain format and parsing it is up to you. You can manually check what does the form submit when you do it manually, and do the same thing via curl.

Answer (score 0):

You also may try phpcrawl (http://phpcrawl.cuab.de), seems to fit all your needs.
(See "addPostData()"-method)